# Identify Subplots in Plotly

Tags: javascript, plotly

Is it possible to identify in which subplot my mouse is ? I got a function with which i can add points to my trace, but my problem is that this point gets shown in both subplots as soon as i add one, that's why i'd like to be able to get the number/the name of my subplot to differentiate in which subplot an even has fired.
So its important for me to figure out in which subplot an event has fired.
Here is an example of Plotly with two subplots with a click function. Instead of showing me the data in the plots, it would be important for me to see in which subplot it have clicked !

```
var trace1 = {
x: [1, 2, 3],
y: [4, 5, 6],
type: 'scatter'
};

var trace2 = {
x: [20, 30, 40],
y: [50, 60, 70],
xaxis: 'x2',
yaxis: 'y2',
type: 'scatter'
};

var data = [trace1, trace2];

var layout = {
grid: {rows: 1, columns: 2, pattern: 'independent'},
};
var myPlot = document.getElementById('myDiv')
Plotly.newPlot(myPlot, data, layout);
myPlot.on('plotly_click', function(data){
  var pts = '';
  for(var i=0; i < data.points.length; i++){
      pts = 'x = '+data.points[i].x +'\ny = '+
          data.points[i].y.toPrecision(4) + '\n\n';
  }
  alert('Closest point clicked:\n\n'+pts);
});





  <head>
      <!-- Load plotly.js into the DOM -->
      <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.3.1.min.js'></script>
  </head>

  <body>
      <div id='myDiv'><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the MouseEvent data it seems you can identify a subplot using:

```
myPlot.on('plotly_click', function (data) {
  console.log(data.event.target.dataset.subplot)
});
```

Clicking on the first subplot logs `xy`. Clicking on the second subplot logs `x2y2`.